how to proceed with installation interrupt because of problematic symlinks
THe following error interrupted a process to update libvips on a local macOS machine using homebrew
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /opt/homebrew
Could not symlink share/pmix/help-pmix-mca-base.txt
Target /opt/homebrew/share/pmix/help-pmix-mca-base.txt
is a symlink belonging to open-mpi. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink open-mpi


To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite pmix

Follows a list generated by homebrew, of files that would be deleted, but that is pretty opaque without an understanding of which libraries have existing dependencies and the posssible consequences.
What is a safe way to proceed here?
